# Nuke this tag please

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-deletion

the tag in question is here: 'javascipt' https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascipt/info

Just by reading the about:

> This is tag created out of people misspelling JavaScript.

I do not believe this is an acceptable tag for the main site seeing how it is for a typo.